# How to determine if a random variable is $\mathcal F$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

For example :

Consider the state space $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, the $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{F} = \{(-\infty, 0], (0, \infty), 0, \mathbb{R}\}$ and the random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
                3 & \omega < 0\\
                5 & \omega \geq 0
            \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Is $X$ $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: The definition of a random variable is a measurable real-valued function defined on a sample space. So to be more precise, you should ask something like "is this function measurable?" or "is this map a random variable?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure Theory - Building Intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701637/measure-theory-building-intuition)

Answer (score 3):

Measurability of a random variable $X$ is defined based on the inverse image.

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space and $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{G})$ be a measurable space. Let $X$ be a random variable that is defined on this probability space by: 
$$X: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{G})$$

Then, $X$ is said to be $\mathcal{F}-$measurable if for all $E \in \mathcal{G}, X^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{F}$. Every pullback in the image of $X$ should be in the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}$.

For your example, $\mathcal{G} = \big\{\{3\}, \{5\}, \{3,5\}, \emptyset\big\}$.

I think you mean to define $\mathcal{F} := \big\{(-\infty, 0), [0,\infty), \emptyset, \mathbb{R}\big\}\;$ based on your equality condition in your definition of $X$. In this way, you can verify that the above holds.

Comment: I also suspect that the definition of $\mathcal{F}$ was meant to include the empty set, instead of the number $0$, which is not a set. However, I suspect the intervals were meant to be $(-\infty, 0]$ and $(0, \infty)$, as written, which would make $X$ not $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if $\{\omega:X(\omega)<c\}\in \mathcal{F}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

1. $c<3$. In this case, since no $\omega$ satisfies, $\{\omega:X(\omega)<c\}=\varnothing\in \mathcal{F}$
2. $3 \leqslant c<5$. In this case, $\{\omega:X(\omega)=3\}=(-\infty,0) \in \mathcal{F}$
3. $c \geqslant 5$. In this case, $\{\omega:X(\omega)=5\}=[0,+\infty)=0\cup(0,+\infty)\in \mathcal{F}$

So $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: Why is it not the case that for the 3rd condition we dont include the interval $(-\infty , 0)$ as its image is certainly less than $c$ which is greater than $3$?

Comment: Because in OP, 
$X(\omega) =3 \:\text{for } \omega < 0 \:\text{and } X(\omega) =5  \:\text{for }  \omega \geq 0$

Comment: I get that, but don't we want $\{\omega : X(\omega) \le 5\}$ for example, would that not include the sets for which $X(\omega) = 3$ and $X(\omega) = 5$ since both $5$ and $3$ are $\le 5$.

Comment: No, you misunderstood the $X(\omega)$. There must be a value for $X(\omega)$ for $\omega>0$