# Determine whether $X$ is a measurable RV with the information of $|X|$?

Tags: measure-theory

I am working on a problem to determine the measurability of a random variable.

Define $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\Omega = \{\omega_i : i= 1, \ldots, 5\}$.

where $X\{\omega_1\}=0, X\{\omega_2\}=-1, X\{\omega_3\}=1, X\{\omega_4\}=2, X\{\omega_5\}=-2$. The textbook define $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for $X$ and $|X|$.

I need to determine whether X is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable RV and whether X is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable RV.

My think:
$\mathcal{G}$ contains only information of absolute value of $X(\omega)$, so by giving  $X(\omega) = 1$, we can't determine whether it is coming from $\omega_2$ or $\omega_3$. So X is not a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable RV.

In a similar idea, $X$ has more information needed to determine the value of $|X|$, so $|X|$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable RV.

I'm not sure if the idea is right or vice versa, and how to write that in mathematical language. From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1191490/523392), I want to list all the conditions, but it feels too simple.

Comment: $\{\omega_3\}=X^{-1}(1)$ does not belong to $\mathcal G$ but it belongs to $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Is $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ the inclusion function?

Comment: You provide values of the $\omega_i$ but I would rather expect values of the $X(\omega_i)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you! How can I prove the existence of $\mathcal{G}$? Should I list all the possible?

Comment: @drhab Yes, that's my mistake.

Comment: $|X|$ induces on $\Omega$ the following partition: $\{\{\omega_1\},\{\omega_2,\omega_3\},\{\omega_4,\omega_5\}\}$. The elements of $\mathcal G$ are the sets that can be written as a union of sets in this partition (there are $2^3=8$). For $X$ we have similarly the finer partition consisting of all singletons.